# How do I start as a quantum computing programmer?

Tags: programming, resource-request, q#

How do I learn Q#? What languages should I know prior to learning Q#? How do I get started with quantum computing?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the first big reference I would highlight is [qsharp.community](https://qsharp.community/). Its a community org where we work on projects and collecting learning materials for Q#. Contributions are always welcome, so just make a PR on a repo or hop on the [gitter](https://gitter.im/qsharp-community/community) and say hi!

I'll also add that I am working on a textbook that is currently in Early Access called [Learn Quantum Computing with Python and Q#](https://bit.ly/qsharp-book). It is intended for folks who want to learn how to program for a quantum computer, and learn the basics of how a quantum computer works along the way. Only knowledge prerequisites are programming in some language (Python helps but not really required) and a bit of linear algebra (multiple matrices and vectors sort of stuff). My co-author @chris-granade and I would love feedback on what is currently out on the forums associated with the book, and there are discount codes floating around for conferences and podcasts and such, hmu and I can help find one for ya!

Answer (score 3):

To get started with quantum computing in general, you need to start by learning some of the theory behind it - unlike classical programming, you don't have any intuition about what is going on from your previous experiences, so jumping right into programming might be a bit too steep. There are a lot of resources out there to help you with this, you might want to check out other questions tagged with [resource-request](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) or the [Awesome Quantum Computing list](https://github.com/desireevl/awesome-quantum-computing).

---

For Q#, here are the resources you might want to start with:

- [Official documentation](http://docs.microsoft.com/quantum), including a [brief review of quantum computing concepts](https://docs.microsoft.com/quantum/concepts/).
- [Quantum Katas](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas) - self-paced programming exercises and tutorials designed to accompany a course on quantum computing theory. Each kata consists of a set of exercises of increasing complexity for you to solve and a behind-the-scenes testing harness which checks whether your code is correct, providing you immediate feedback, so I believe they are a great way to learn (*disclaimer: I am the primary maintainer of the Quantum Katas project*).
  The existing katas cover a nice set of introductory topics, and we are working on more tutorials bridging the gap between "not knowing anything about quantum computing" and "knowing enough to solve first exercises" - check back in two-three weeks :-)
- [Awesome Q# list](https://github.com/ebraminio/awesome-qsharp) lists a variety of other resources, including blogs, videos, standalone tutorials and even a book!

Finally, I don't think it's as important what programming language you know before learning Q# as just knowing some programming language. C# and Python come to mind first, since they both allow to run Q# from them (you'll need a classical program to invoke quantum code), but you don't need them to start solving the katas.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with q#, but I have used [qiskit](https://qiskit.org) extensively. Qiskit is a python package supported by IBM, so obviously you need to know python. There are many tutorials and instructive Jupyter notebooks on the qiskit syntax and even some basic quantum mechanics. A [qiskit based textbook](https://community.qiskit.org/textbook/) was just released. I haven't read it yet, but maybe you'll find it useful. Lastly, linear algebra is the language of qubits. You will want to have a solid understanding of linear algebra.